# UNIX sendmail is not supporting Javascript

Tags: unix

In script I have

```
(
echo "From: me@xyz.com "
echo "To: them@xyz.com "
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; " 
echo ' boundary="some.unique.value.ABC123/server.xyz.com"' 
echo "Subject: Test HTML e-mail." 
echo "This is a MIME-encapsulated message" 
echo "--some.unique.value.ABC123/server.xyz.com" 



echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat output.htm
echo "--some.unique.value.ABC123/server.xyz.com"



) | sendmail -t
```

Here, All my HTML content is working fine.
The contents which contains javascript is not reflecting in the output.

The above output.htm file contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
......
......
<script>
<style>
......
......
</style>
</head>

<body>
.....
.....
</body>

</html>
```

When I am trying to send this above code in **sendmail**, The javascript part is getting commented out and I am getting the output except the Javascript code.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I don't think it's sendmail, but rather your MTA or MUA. If my webmail client executed random JavaScript code sent to me by random strangers, I would be very sad indeed.

Comment: @Thomas: though your concern certainly makes sense this is not an issue for the sending party. It is a question of a secure mail client and not connected to this questions content.

Comment: What I was getting at is, that pkawar probably didn't look at the email that sendmail injected into his local mailer daemon, but at the resulting email at the other end of the line, after it's gone through one or more MTAs that might have mangled it for security reasons.